# Search inside an array of strings

Tags: c#

```
string[] words = {"januar", "februar", "marec", "april", "maj", "junij", "julij",    
"avgust", "september", "oktober", "november", "december"};
```

I have word "ja" for example or "dec". How can I get "januar" or "december" from an array of string? Is there any fast solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using the newer versions of C# (3.0 and up) you can use LINQ:

```
// to find a match anywhere in the word
words.Where(w => w.IndexOf(str, 
    StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0);

// to find a match at the beginning only
words.Where(w => w.StartsWith(str, 
    StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

Comment: `StringComparison` exists for a reason.  **Use it**!  `İ i I ı`

Comment: @Slaks - Updated to use IndexOf instead of Contains since Contains doesn't have an overload that takes a StringComparison. Is there a better way?

Comment: @SLaks - Interesting. Seems like that's a bit of an oversight. Useful extension method though.

Answer (score 5):

You can use LINQ:

```
words.FirstOrDefault(w => w.StartsWith(str, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
```

If there was no match, this will return `null`.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<string> words = new List<string>() { "January", "February", "March", "April" };

var result = words.Where(w => w.StartsWith("jan", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

Will find the results that start with whatever criteria you provide, and ignore the case (optional.)

Answer (score 0):

You can Use simple Regular Expressions as well...
string[] words = { "januar", "februar", "marec", "april", "maj", "junij", "julij", "avgust", "september","oktober", "november", "december" 
                         };

```
    string sPattern = "ja";

    foreach (string s in words)
    {


        if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(s, sPattern, System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("  (match for '{0}' found)", sPattern);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Doing this with a regex is like using a chainsaw to slice an apple.